# When does /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions get loaded?

Tags: zsh, alias, autocomplete

As far as I can tell, my `.zshrc` doesn't manually source anything in `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions`. If I try to write, in my `.zshrc`, an alias for a command that has completions set up in `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions`, it doesn't work. However, if I edit the completions file in `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions` to add my aliasing at the end, then it does work.

For example, let's say I have a program `foo`, and a program `bar` that is an enhanced version of `foo`. And let's say I have tab completions in `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions` for `foo` but not for `bar`. So when I write `alias foo=bar` and `compdef bar=foo` in my `.zshrc`, the tab completions don't work. But if I write those two lines in `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions`, in the same file that sets up `foo`'s tab completions, then it does work.

It seems like `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions` is loaded after `.zshrc`, but I couldn't find documentation on it. I'd like to know where vendor completions fit in during zsh's loading sequence, so I can confirm what is the right thing to do, as a package maintainer.

Comment: There is no mention of `vendor-completions` in the zsh source code. That must be an addition by your Unix vendor. Which is it?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm running Debian buster.

Comment: See `/usr/share/doc/zsh-common/README.Debian`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see, that explains it. It is documented (briefly) in that readme. I could not find a repo link from the Debian package page for zsh, nor in the wiki, so I still don't know when `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions` gets loaded, but at least I know this isn't standard.

Comment: Actually, I was too quick to comment. I see that it explains that this path is included in `fpath`, which makes this [easy to figure out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20451076/691859) If you want to write this up as an answer then I am happy to accept it and give you some rep, otherwise I will answer my own question.